# How to remove downward lines from sequential cumulatives

Tags: r, ggplot2

The code and the figure illustrate the periodic cumulative consumption of a resource, for instance the daily use of electricity for two households.

I would like to suppress the steep vertical downward segments.
The ‘day’ variable must (presumably) play a role in the ggplot() statement.
I have tried several ways of doing so, but have not yet been successful.

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

```
ndays <- 3
readingsperday <- 10

timeofday <- 0:(-1+ndays*readingsperday)/readingsperday
day <- trunc(timeofday)

randu1 <-c( t(cbind( 0, matrix(runif( ndays*(-1+readingsperday)),nrow=ndays) ) ) ) 
randu2 <-c( t(cbind( 0, matrix(runif( ndays*(-1+readingsperday)),nrow=ndays) ) ) ) 
  
mytib <- tibble(
  time = 0:(-1+ndays*readingsperday)/readingsperday,
  day = trunc(time),
  randu1  ,  
  randu2 )  %>%
  group_by(day) %>%
  mutate(cumul1 = cumsum(randu1) )  %>%
  mutate(cumul2 = cumsum(randu2) )  %>%
  select(-c(randu1, randu2) ) %>%
  gather( `cumul1`, `cumul2`, value = 'value', key = 'meter'  ) 

ggplot(mytib, aes(x=time, y=value, color=meter) ) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could group your lines by interaction of day and meter.

Alternatively, you could facet by your day - and optionally for the visual effect of "one graph", remove the spacing between the facets.

See below for both options.

#### option 1 - grouping

```r
ggplot(mytib, aes(x=time, y=value, color=meter, group = interaction(day, meter)) ) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]

#### option 2 - facetting

```r
ggplot(mytib, aes(x=time, y=value, color=meter) ) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom") +
  ## facet by day with free scale
  facet_grid(~day, scales = "free_x") +
  ## remove expansion
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  ## remove space between facets
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "in"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Just like that! It works perfectly.